# Hydrogenation stereochemistry-Pd,Pt, Ni catalysts

Tags: organic-chemistry, hydrogen, catalysis

When my textbook talks about hydrogenation using Pt, Pd or Ni heterogeneous catalysts, it never mentions if it is anti or syn addition.
It simply jumps on to say that for alkynes, NiB2 (P-2) catalysts and Lindlar's catalysts are syn hydrogenation.
Can someone tell me if using Pt gives syn or anti for alkynes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using any *transition* metal catalyst (Pt, Pd, Ni) for hydrogenation of alkynes results in syn hydrogenation to not alkenes but alkanes. Using Lindlar's catalyst results in syn hydrogenation of an alkyne to an alkene.

In the case of sodium metal (*not* a transition metal) in ammonia, hydrogenation of alkynes results in a trans alkene.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Pt gives you syn addition of hydrogens to alkynes, but Pt without anything else (Lindlar's catalyst) will hydrogenate your alkyne to an alkane.

Comment: Really!? So, if I write a reaction of 
CH3CCCH3 --> CH3CH=CHCH3 (   H2,Pt)
I am actually wrong because that will directly undergo another hydrogenation?
My whole life has been a lie :O

Comment: Yes if you don't use Lindlar's catalyst with the transition metal catalyst, then the alkyne will be hydrogenated to an alkane. Sure, the alkyne passes through an alkene, but it's hard to isolate this alkene. http://www.chem.ucalgary.ca/courses/350/Carey5th/Ch09/ch9-6.html

Comment: @Dissenter Hydrogenation is not a concerted process.

Comment: Ok perfect. Now I get the whole point of using Lindlar's or the NiB2 (P-2). GREAT HELP AS USUAL.

Comment: @ron i got that from here: http://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2013/04/02/alkene-addition-pattern-3-the-concerted-pathway/

Comment: @Dissenter  I agree with your diagram, 2 hydrogen atoms are not transferred in a single step, the reaction is not concerted.

Comment: Is the linked article incorrect or am I interpreting it incorrectly then?

Comment: @ron, I retract, that link is correct!

Comment: The link says that hydroboration and epoxidation are concerted.  It does not say hydrogenation on a metal catalyst is concerted - such hydrogenations are two-step, not concerted.

Comment: @ron I'm referring to the part where he says " That is, products of syn addition as a result of a concerted mechanism?" and goes on to list "Hydrogenation" as his first bullet point in that particular list. So the author's incorrect? He _does_ say that hydrogenation is concerted. Also the title of the article is "The “Concerted” Pathway."

Comment: "In the transition state for this reaction, each of the two hydrogen atoms are delivered to the same face of the alkene. " the author of the link also says that; that seems to weakly suggest that hydrogenation is not concerted (note his usage of "each"). I'm on your side ron, but can you provide some paper or research showing that hydrogenation is not concerted?

Comment: yes, both hydrogens are delivered in a step-wise fashion, this is definitely not concerted, look at diimide reduction for an example of a  concerted hydrogenation.

Comment: One final comment, some metals (Na\NH3 - it's not a transition metal, but still...) produce pure trans hydrogenation of an alkyne.

Comment: Ron you are awesome. I forgot about Na/NH3. Thank you!

Comment: You should edit in any information that is in addition to your original answer and then remove the comments. It is now really hard to follow. I even do not see any real relationship to the original question. It seems like the answer is **only** hidden in the comments. In general it should be avoided to discuss anything in the comments.

Answer (score 4):

All catalytic hydrogenations involving solid metal catalysts transfer hydrogen in a syn fashion to the alkyne to produce the corresponding cis-olefin.  The following figure provides a mechanism that illustrates why the

[image]

addition must be syn.

But, with alkynes there are problems.  First, reduction of the resultant alkene is faster than reduction of the starting alkyne, so product mixtures of alkenes and alkanes will result unless poisoned catalysts ([Lindlar catalyst](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindlar_catalyst)) are used or the reaction is stopped early.  A second problem often observed is that the resultant alkene usually remains adsorbed on the catalyst surface.  Consequently cis-trans isomerization of the alkene can take place leading to further contamination of the initial cis-product.

Comment: "First, reduction of the resultant alkene is faster than reduction of the starting alkyne". Why?

Comment: @yolo123  the first pi bond to be reduced in an alkyne is stronger than the second pi (alkene) bond, so once the strong (alkyne) bond is reduced, the second pi bond goes quick.

Comment: By reduced, you mean hydrogenated? 
By the way, oxidizing something is equivalent to dehydrogenating?
And oxylation= adding oxygen atom?
Sorry, I'm just orgo newbie!

Comment: 1) "By reduced, you mean hydrogenated?" Yes; 2) Yes, dehydrogenation is an example of oxidation.

Comment: I would expect that the coordination of the alkyne is the rate determining step. After that the alkyne would most likely already be coordinated and therefore be further reduced.