# Trans-hydrogenation of alkenes

Tags: reaction-mechanism, stereochemistry

Both [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/15387/hydrogenation-stereochemistry-pd-pt-ni-catalysts) and [that](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/44783/hydrogenation-of-alkynes-to-trans-alkenes) question seem to indicate that the hydrogenation of alkenes to alkanes or alkynes to alkenes is always a *syn* process.

However since hydrogenation is *not* a concerted process, I do not see why we could not have a non-negligible (although small) portion of the *trans* product.

Following this reaction mechanism for *syn* additions : [image]

before the penultimate step (the addition of the second hydrogen), can't the molecule simply rotate around the $\ce{C-C}$ axis (I expect this should be possible with small enough alkenes) ?

The [Wikibooks article on alkenes](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Organic_Chemistry/Alkenes) does indicate that typically the hydrogenation of alkenes leads to only $98\%$ of the *syn* product, but I have been unable to find more precise information elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, the *trans* product probably will be formed in small quantities. Given the very small size of a hydrogen atom I would guess that the second hydrogen transfer step is very fast, so rotation is unlikely, given that it will be sterically hindered.

Comment: Is there some experimental data with concrete examples, and which maybe shows how it evolves with the size of the alkene ? I haven't been able to find any @bon

Comment: I don't have the time or resources to search for it now but maybe someone else will turn up something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This link](https://www.thevespiary.org/rhodium/Rhodium/chemistry/redux.htm) has a good summary of hydrogenation. Syn addition is very much preferred because of the way the molecule 'adheres' to the surface. As you note, however, there are cases where anti-addition is observed - particularly for sterically hindered molecules such as 1,2-dimethylcyclohex-1-ene which shows up to 30% of the trans/anti-addition product (which also so happens to be the thermodynamic product).

The reason we see the syn-addition more often is because the Hydrogen atom attack happens really quickly (it's the kinetic product). If you pump more heat energy into the reaction though, you could expect to see more trans product - but this is dangerous as hydrogen is explosive.