# How does a transition metal(eg Zn,Pd,Pt etc) break the hydrogen bond in catalytic reduction

Tags: organic-chemistry, catalysis

I want to know what exactly happens with the hydrogen molecules and transition metals in catalytic reduction leading to breaking of hydrogen bonds and forming two hydrogen atoms

Comment: I don't think it's well understood.

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/15387/hydrogenation-stereochemistry-pd-pt-ni-catalysts